# JQuery - Position Popup in relative to button(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position a popup relative to its button or the button that is clicked with jquery. I'd like to position the popup in a way that doesn't cover up the button itself. Position it to the left, right, above or below the button that is clicked.

Now I know I can do this by writing more html popups and css but there got to be a way to dynamically use one div and position it with jquery. I tried using offsets and position (at one point) but I couldn't get it to work. Frankly, I'm very entry level with js and jquery so forgive my noobness.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

JS:

```
 $('.trends').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>What trends could potentially drive growth in the U.S.?</p>');
     /* if I add this and zero out the positioning via css the pop gets offset but its way far away from this parent.
     var offset = $(this).offset();
                $('.questions').css('left',offset.left);    
                $('.questions').css('top',offset.top);*/

 });

 $('.consumer').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>Even though we have low inflation, consumers are not increasing their spending. Why?</p>');
 });

 $('.industry').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>What factors drove crude oil prices to fall and which industries benefited?</p>');
 });

 $('.henn').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>MESSAGE FROM OUR PRESIDENT</p>');
     var offset = $(this).offset();
 $('.question').html('<p>What trends could potentially drive growth in the U.S.?</p>');

 });
 $('.equity').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>The U.S. stock market has been rising for more than six years. What do you see ahead for equities?</p>');
 });

 $('.balance').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>what does it look like for companies balance sheets?</p>');
 });


 $('.close').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).parent().hide();
     $('.items').removeClass('no-effect');

 });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nick1572/3d7v0o25/30/)

Comment: Ugh thanks Michael!!!! SMH!! :)

Comment: you should consider the button's width and height along with offset top and left to achieve this

Comment: Im using susy which calculates the buttons in percentages. there is no height only padding. So I assume I will have to add that. Thanks!

Heres the width of a button....
 width: 31.4814814815%;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a separate function to display the question, which takes the clicked button and the question as parameters:

```
function showQuestion(button, question) {
  var offset = button.offset();
  $('.question').html(question);

  $('.questions')
    .fadeIn()
    .css({
      left: Math.min(offset.left, $(window).innerWidth()-$('.questions').outerWidth()),
      top: offset.top + button.innerHeight()
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$('.trends').click(function () {
  showQuestion(
    $(this), 
    '<p>What trends could potentially drive growth in the U.S.?</p>'
  );
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vefjb4f5/)

The `css` left calculation ensures that the question will always be on-screen.

Comment: AGHHHHH!!!!!! Thank you Rick!!!! Much appreciated!!!! Crap i really know nothing! What is the button in the argument? what is that referencing? (button, question)

Comment: The button parameter is the actual button that was clicked; for example, `$('.trends')`.  That's because we pass `$(this)` to `showQuestion()` within the click handler.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that!!! Seriously thank you very much. And...thank you apaul for your answer as well!!

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem was `.filter` being set to `position: relative;`.

If an absolute positioned element has a relative positioned parent the absolute element will be positioned in relation to the parent not the document.

If you remove that it gets a little easier to use `.offset()` to position the question:

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3d7v0o25/35/)**

```
 $('.trends').click(function () {
     $('.questions').fadeIn();
     $('.question').html('<p>What trends could potentially drive growth in the U.S.?</p>');
     /* See change here*/
     var offset = $(this).offset();
     $('.questions').css('top', offset.top + $(this).height());

 });

.filter {
    width: 98.1481481481%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.9259259259%;
    margin-right: 0.9259259259%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /*position: relative; see change here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a $(...).position() function in jQuery that should help you out. I refactored your code a bit to avoid repeating lines, but the gist of it is:

```
function popup(jqBtn, question){
  // mind that the .position does not account for borders etc.
  var btn = $(jqBtn).parents('.buttons'),
      posLeft = btn.position().left + btn.outerWidth(),
      posTop = btn.position().top;

  $('.questions').fadeIn();
  $('.question').html(question);
  $('.questions')
    .appendTo(btn.parent())
    .css('left', posLeft + 'px')
    .css('top', posTop + 'px');    
}

// a sample of binding a button to the popup() function
$('.trends').click(function () {
  popup(this, '<p>What trends could potentially drive growth in the U.S.?</p>');
});
```

So the function re-appends the 'questions' div to have the same parent as the button. The button is found based on the element clicked, traversing up the structure to find an element of '.buttons' class. That might need adjusting if the structure gets more complex.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swfjs2xq/)

Comment: I tried this method as well. Thank you. One thing, if I needed the buttons on the right hand side to show their pop on the left could i add an if statement in that function to handle that? as it stands right now for the right side buttons the pops open far right. Could I add x, y coordinates in the params in that function?  Then when the function is called on the click I can  fine tune where the pops are located per button

Comment: Exactly. You might check the position of the button and decide left-or-right, you can even look at total document size, and if oversized, adjust the position of the popup.

Comment: Oh no....my calculations are coming out like this... 
`Object { top=0,  left=0.000007402343750406715}` Is there a way to round that?

Comment: I tried...`posLeft = Math.round(btn.position().left) + btn.outerWidth(),`
but when I log it, it still comes out as that long string of numbers. Does that look right?

`console.log(btn.position().left);`

Comment: btn.outerWidth must come like this. Put it inside the parentheses and it'll be fine. Another way to put it is: posLeft = Math.floor(btn.position().left + btn.outerWidth);

Comment: Anyway, it's actually supposed to be non-integer. The calculations behind the scenes use all the funny units css provides, hence the result.

Comment: Checked in Chrome and indeed it gives me smaller numbers. FF was still logging it long. Tnx! Yeh susy creates the percentages. Next time i'll think about that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82981/discussion-between-lnickel-and-ptrk).