# PopUp does not appear below the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, flexbox

I recently started with css flexbox design and stumbled over a problem.

I have two boxes in column direction. In the first column I have a button to open the popUp. 
The popUp should

- be opened right below the button
- should overlay the second box

But I can only make one of those two things work and not both together.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/t9z7x13w/2/)

html:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="button" id="toggle" value="pop up" onclick="togglePopUp()"/>
    <div class="popup" id="pop" style="display: none">
      <input type="button"  id="toggle" class="close" value="close" onclick="togglePopUp()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function togglePopUp() {
  if (document.getElementById('pop').style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById('pop').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('pop').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

css:

```
.popup {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.close {
  float: left;
  color: red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've added additional explanation to my answer. I apologize if it was unclear previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way for me to do this would be to throw it in a wrapper with the following css:

```
.popwrap{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:1px;
  position:static;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a demo of your work in action:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeKGQL

**Edit:**

### Further Explanation:

Apologies, but the key to the wrapper here is that I have the position for `.popwrap` set as **`static`**. This is essentially the 'default' (also known as `initial`) value for `position`.

In order for z-index to be correctly applied in an expected manner to an element, you need a position applied to that element. It's how the browser comes up with the various layers to elements on a page.

That's not the only thing at play, here. You're also looking to have a child 'popup' element not disturb the flow or positioning of any other elements around it. The popup element you have needs to be set to '`absolute`'.

For further reading on the stacking context and the factors at play in your example, I invite you to visit these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

I've been awake for about 36 hours at this point, (long project) but if this explanation wasn't clear, I'd be happy to give it another stab after I sleep.

Comment: HI MassDebates, this is working. But can you explain it a little bit more in detail, please?

Comment: I apologize, yes, I'll explain it more in an edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
.popup {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
    left: 43%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 31%;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9z7x13w/3/)**

Comment: This is not working dynamicaly. e.g. resizing the window.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Pls visit the following link.I think you can solve your problem.

[JQuery - Position Popup in relative to button(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319823/jquery-position-popup-in-relative-to-buttons)

```
and see the following demo.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vefjb4f5/

Comment: I'm not a fan of this jsfiddle's solution. Ctrl + Scroll (Changing browser zoom) messes up positioning of the popup element in relation to the button.